# android - total replacement of the lock screen for root device

Tags: android, root, replace, lockscreen, keyguard

suppose i make an app only for root devices , which will allow to replace the lock screen (the screen that appears when the device's screen is being awaken) .

i know that there are ways to do so without root , but they are all considered a workaround and on some devices they don't work well at all (like the sony erricson , which shows their default locker after unlocking with the installed locker) .

is such a thing possible? maybe there is a path to the apk (or whatever) that is responsible of showing the lock screen?

is it also possible to backup what is responsible for the lock screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The android lockscreen are not handled by apk's. They're part of the framework itself ( except for the FaceUnlock). What you could do is to add another IBinder interface to "com.android.internal.policy.impl.LockPatternKeyguardView.java". Have a look at how "FaceUnlock" is implemented.

Regards,

Robert

Comment: do you mean that such a thing is possible only on android 4 ? do you suggest implementing "IFaceLockInterface" for a service that will listen to some kind of intent , which is probably IFaceLockInterface.class.getName() ? i think that if it's possible , there is no need for root , right?

Comment: Actually i can't tell you anything about versions other than ics. I'd say you can implement a service that uses the IFaceLockInterface without the phone rooted... give it a try :)

Comment: sadly i don't have a device with ICS , but i can always use an emulator... this could take some time , so if there is no other answer , i guess you deserve a "V" . :)

Comment: damn , there is no face unlock on the emulator , and even if there was , i wouldn't be able to use it since i don't think the emulator can use the webcam. if anyone think it could be handy , here are some useful links: http://source-android.frandroid.com/frameworks/base/core/java/com/android/internal/policy/IFaceLockInterface.aidl https://gist.github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_base/blob/c9c417c85d08074e5ececd5c74db1364e9c097c2/core/java/com/android/internal/policy/IFaceLockCallback.aidl